# Casperjs: How to evaluate a page in intervals of x sec?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, setinterval, wait, casperjs

I want to load a page and then evaluate it multiple times in intervals of x sec. Here is two ways I've tried:
First using JS setInterval:

```js
casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

casper.thenEvaluate(function() {
    window.x = 0;
    var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
       console.log("iter " + window.x);

       <do some evaluation here>

       if (++window.x === 5) {
           window.clearInterval(intervalID);
       }
    }, 10000);
});
casper.each(list, function(self, i) {
    self.wait(10000, function() {
        last = i;
        this.echo('Using this.wait ' + i);
    });
});

casper.waitFor(function() {
    return last === list[list.length - 1] && 5 === this.getGlobal('x');
}, function() {
    this.echo('All done.').exit();
});

casper.run(function() {});
```

Second using CasperJS wait:

```js
casper.start(link, function() {
    for(i = 1; i < ITER; i++){
        CurrentIter++;
        this.wait(WAIT_TO, function() {
                this.echo("I've waited for" + WAIT_TO + "ms.");
                this.then(function() {
                    this.evaluate(<some evaluation>);
                });   
        });
    }
});
casper.run();
```

It seems that they should do the same job, but I get different results. Can any one give me some hints on this?

Comment: You haven't said what the results are or how they differ. Also, how is `list` defined in the first snippet.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add the first line of the code, list is just a list of intervals:var last, list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];.In the evaluation function, I look for the number of some DOM elements. As websites add and remove elements to their DOM over time, the code should return different values in each interval. But the value returned in the same interval is different for the above codes.Notice the value of WAIT_TO(in the second code) is 10000(interval value in the first code).Thanks Artjom.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. I see no reason they would behave differently. That `casper.each()` loop in the first snippet is a bit awkward. You should simply use a longer timeout for the final `waitFor`: `casper.waitFor(function() { return 5 === this.getGlobal('x'); }, function() { this.echo('All done.'); }, function() { this.echo('Timeout'); }, (list.length+1) * 10000);`